# php library to convert cdr files in any reasonable format

Tags: php

I am looking for a php module able to convert [CDR files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDR_%28file_format%29#CDR_file_format) in any raster-based image formats (jpg, gif). Can anyone help with ideas or a solution?

---

I want to add some additional information about my question as it was part of extended solution and there were no materials in the internet.

My initial task was to create a pdf file from uploaded html form filled with unicode data. User can upload image files (in cdr format) that have to be merged into pdf as well.

I used mpdf which actually supports everything (unicode fonts, html rendering, image rendering, etc) but doesn't support cdr. Thanks to uniconvertor I managed to convert cdr to svg and store it temporary on server.

2 remarks:

1. I converted cdr to pdf and tried to merge 2 files but mergeing pdfs is not the strongest side of mpdf convertor.
2. I evaluated ImageMagick which can further convert svg to jpeg. Although this can do the trick ImageMagick is cumbersome to install on Windows.
   If anyone is following my steps just use svg with mpdf (although svg is a vector based image just as cdr), perhaps because svg is open source format mpdf supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not going to be a native PHP solution for this; ImageMagick can't process CDR files, either.

This Open Source tool looks very promising: [SK1 UniConvertor](http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor)

> UniConvertor is a universal vector graphics translator. It is a command line tool which uses sK1 object model to convert one format to another.